# understand 'struct proto' and 'struct proto_ops' in the kernel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I'm studying the tcp/ip implementation, specifically sockets layer, and there's something I don't quite understand about a few structure.

I know that 'struct proto_ops' is used to define the operations, e.g. bind/connect/accept, and every socket has a specified proto_ops.

On the other hand, 'struct proto' defines new protocol and the structure also defines function pointers for accept/bind/setsockopt/getsockopt/etc. methods.

I read lots of code in $linux/net/ and I don't see where does it use the operations defined via 'struct proto', so I'm not sure how these methods are being used in the code?

Could someone clarify this for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is the most headache problem when a newbie try to create a new protocol

**Explain:**
Both structures have member elements with similar names although they represent different functions

- struct prot_ops: used for communication between socket layer and transport layer
- struct prot: used for communicate with system calls

**Example:**
when you call a system call in userspace, ex connect(), prot_ops_connect() will be call first.

- In fucntion prot_ops_connect(), we need to call sk->sk_prot->connect()
- And sk->sk_prot->connect() will call proto_connect() automatically

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

You can image like this.There are three layer:

```
BSD sock->inet sock->tcp/udp sock
```

corresponding ops:

```
BSD api->proto_ops->proto
```

If you read sys_socket() and sys_read(), you will get the same answers.

Hopefully, this can help you:-)